# android cordova sharedpreference deleting during force close

Tags: android, cordova, sharedpreferences

We are facing an issue with android SharedPreferences in our application. Our application is a cordova application. We are storing few data in the SharedPreferences. For example, storing userid, last visited page html contents, few json values. 
Following are code samples for managing sharedpreferences (get/set/remove).

```
//get
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cordova.getActivity());
Object obj = sharedPrefs.getAll().get(key);

//remove
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cordova.getActivity());
if (sharedPrefs.contains(key)) {
    Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.remove(key);
}

//store
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cordova.getActivity());
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
```

The storing retrieving deleting everything working fine. The problem we are facing is, the data is not persisting in a consistent manner. 
For example, user opens the app and then he force close the app, again takes the app. All data in the sharedpreference is persists. But when he force close 2nd time and come back to the app once again, then the data from the sharedpreference is deleted. I could not find any log in the logcat also. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue, currently using https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage plugin. Any ideas how to solve this?